# Настройка фильтров django

Tags: python-3.x, django, django-admin

есть вопрос, в django admin  у меня есть простенький кастомный поиск который просто добавляет в query string данные типа https://admin/?asd=1
и также у меня включены фильтры из коробки с помощью list_filter=(... , ...) когда я ищу поиском и попадаю на страницу результатов все норм, но как только я включаю какой либо фильтр он удаляет данные из query string  и вставляет свои и получается типа https://admin/?filter_1=2,  как мне можно настроить фильтры чтобы при нажатии на фильтр когда я нахожусь на странице результатов по поиску, получался запрос вида
https://admin/?asd=1&filter_1=2
Мне нужно писать кастомный фильтр или все таки можно настроить фильтры из коробки?

Answer (score -2):

Вот пример того, как вы можете создать кастомный фильтр, который будет сохранять существующие параметры запроса:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.utils.http import urlencode

class CustomFilter(admin.SimpleListFilter):
    title = 'Custom Filter'
    parameter_name = 'custom_filter'

    def lookups(self, request, model_admin):
        # Здесь определите ваши варианты фильтрации и их значения
        return (
            ('value1', 'Value 1'),
            ('value2', 'Value 2'),
        )

    def queryset(self, request, queryset):
        if self.value():
            # Получаем текущий запрос в виде словаря
            params = dict(request.GET.items())
            
            # Устанавливаем параметр фильтрации
            params[self.parameter_name] = self.value()
            
            # Пересобираем URL с учетом параметра фильтрации
            url = '?{}'.format(urlencode(params))
            request.META['QUERY_STRING'] = url
            
            # Возвращаем отфильтрованный queryset
            return queryset.filter(**{self.parameter_name: self.value()})
        return queryset

class YourModelAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_filter = (CustomFilter, )

# Регистрируем модель с кастомным фильтром в админке
admin.site.register(YourModel, YourModelAdmin)
```

Comment: [Почему публикация ответов созданных GPT и ChatGPT недопустима?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/gpt-policy)